# "hear him tell" vs. "hear him tells"

Tags: verbs, infinitives

Which one is correct :

> 1. Now let’s hear Marco tell his story.
> 2. Now let’s hear Marco tells his story.

And why?

Answer (score 3):

The first is correct. "Tell" is in the infinitive mood. And you are effectively saying:

*Now let's hear Marco **(to)** tell his story*, except that idiomatically the *to* is elided.

Your second example uses the indicative mood of "tell" - but the sentence already has an indicative main verb - *hear*.

Comment: The difference between the sentences is a bit like the difference between, "May I be honest with you?" and "May I am honest with you?" The latter is ungrammatical.